# Do I need to use "./" for paths when using Grunt?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I resolved an issue simply by replacing "path/to/resource" with "./path/to/resource". Is this important?

```
concat: {
    css: {
        src: [
            'public/css/datepicker.css', 
            'public/css/jquery.tagsinput.css', 
            './src/css/sass_styles.css', // << previously 'src/css/sass_styles.css'
            'application/themes/japantravel/style.css'
        ],
        dest: './public/css/all.css',
    },
    options: {
        process: function(src, filepath) {
            return "/* #### FILENAME: " + filepath + " #### */\n\n" + src + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        }
    }  
},
```

Is it better to use "./" prefix? Why would this matter? I thought both paths were the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally there's no difference, and it shouldn't matter. Adding the prefix `./` is used in cases where the directory or file starts with something that the computer (or framework) wouldn't normally recognize as a file. For example, in a unix shell if you had a directory named `"-really_weird_name"`, it will treat that starting `-r` as an argument and would give an error if you tried to `cd -really_weird_name`. To get around this, you can add `./` — `cd ./-really_weird_name`.

My guess is that grunt sees the `src` in `src/css/...` and thinks you're specifying another source file. What happens if you change the directory name from `"src"`; can you safely remove the leading `./` if you do so?